# Override doctrine lazy loading method to include calculated data to an object

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

let say that I have something like this:

```
class User{
    /**
     * Object that is lazy loaded 
     */
    private $statistic; //object with some stored data and some calculated data
}
```

Some of the $statistic's  properties are stored in the DB but some other of them are calculated by analyzing the user activity (querying data records).

the thing is that I got a $user and when I run $user->getStatistic() as spected, I get the stored $statistic data and I need to add more data using sql queries and I don't know where to program this functionality.
¿overriding the Repository? I try overriding the find() method but it doesn't work

I know that if I use the active record pattern this can be done with no problem giving that I can access the DB in the construct method or the getters maybe, etc.

but I don't know how this could be done with doctrine standard behavior.

I believe that there must be a way to ensure that every instance of the Statistic Class have this calculated data on it.

I'm using symfony... maybe a service or something...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of ways to solve your problem.

### [Doctrine listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html)

This is probably the easiest one. Use Doctrine [`postLoad`](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#postload) event to fill out data you need on your `User` model.

This is a completely valid approach, but has a couple of drawbacks:

1. This will be ran every time doctrine fetches an User entity instance from database. If it fetches a list of 100 users, it will be ran 100 times. This could make a performance problem if you do some time-consuming tasks in there.
2. They are hard to debug: if an error is encountered, events usually make code flow a lot less clear and therefore make debugging harder. If you do simple stuff, and don't overuse them, then it's probably fine, otherwise think about other options.

### Abstracting away doctrine

I'm strongly in favor of this approach and I use it in almost every project.

Even though I'm one of the people who try to have the least amount of layers and indirection necessary, I do think that wrapping data persistence into your own services is a good idea. It isolates rest of your system from having to know **how** your data is stored.

**I suggest not using Doctrine repositories/Entity manager directly. Instead, wrap them in your own services.**

This makes your persistence API squeaky clean and obvious, while giving you ability to manipulate your models before they reach your business logic.

Here is an example of how I would approach your problem:

```
# src/AppBundle/Repository/UserRepository.php

class UserRepository
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function findById($userId)
    {
        $user = $this->em->getRepository(User::class)->find($userId);
        $this->calculateUserStatistics($user);

        return $user;
    }

    public function save(User $user)
    {
        $this->em->persist($user);
        $this->em->flush();
    }

    // ...

    private function calculateUserStatistics(User $user)
    {
        // calculate and set statistics on user object
    }
}
```

This approach has a number of advantages:

#### Decoupling from Doctrine

Your business code is no longer coupled to Doctrine, it doesn't know that Doctrine repositories/entity manager exist at all. If need arises, you can change `UserRepository` implementation to load users from remote API, from file on disk....from anywhere.

#### Model manipulation

It allows you to manipulate your models before they get to business logic, allowing you to calculate values not persisted as a field in database. Eg, to fetch them from Redis, from some API or other...

#### Cleaner API

It makes it really obvious what abilities your system has, making understanding easier and allowing easier testing.

#### Performance optimisation

It doesn't suffer from performance issues as first approach. Take the following example:

You have `$eventsCount` field on your `User` model.

If you load list of 100 users and use first approach, you would need to fire 100 queries to count number of events belonging to each user.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM events WHERE user_id = 1;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM events WHERE user_id = 2;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM events WHERE user_id = 3;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM events WHERE user_id = 4;
...
```

If you have your own UserRepository implementation, however, you can just make method `getEventCountsForUsers($userIds)` which would fire one query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FORM events WHERE user_id IN (:user_ids) GROUP BY user_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own repository to include your own sql queries, Symfony have documented it pretty well in their documentation, see [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes).

Here's how I've done it previously using annotations (this can be done via yaml too, just check the link above)...

Entity:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User
{
    // ...

    private $statistic;

    // ...
}
```

User Repository:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class ProductRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getUserStats()
    {
        // Use query builder to build your query for stats here
    }
}
```

Since your custom repository is extending the EntityRepository, you will still have access to Doctrines lazy load methods (find, findBy, findAll etc...)

Comment: I already try this, but it doesn't work. the statistic object is the problem, unless that in the UserRepository you program the Statistic object load too. But what if I load just the statistic Object? I have to add the same code in the StatisticReposotory? This was my initial approach but must to be a better way

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you don't need exactly User instance.
You can use NEW() syntax in DQL.

```
class UserStatDTO
{
     private $user;
     private $statistic;
     private $sum;

     public function __construct(User $user, $statistic, $sum)
     {
         $this->user = $user;
         $this->statistic = $statistic;
         $this->sum = $sum;
     }

     public function getUser()
     {
         return $this->user;
     }

     public function getSum()
     {
         return $this->sum;
     }

     public function getStatistic()
     {
         return $this->statistic;
     }
}

class UserRepository
{
     public function getUsersWithCalculatedStat()
     { 
           return $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('
                     SELECT NEW UserStatDTO(
                         u, u.statistic, u.count1 + u.count2
                     ) FROM User 
                  ')->getResult();
     }
}
```

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#new-operator-syntax